# Vim loading multiple syntax files instead of just one

Tags: vim

I have put new javascript syntax and indent files in my 'bundle' directory (I use Pathogen). I noticed that VIM loads both my new files as well as the standard files, in particular it loads the standard files after and I fear it may be overwriting the custom ones.

The VIM docs says it should not load the standard files if it found custom one first so I am not sure why this is happening.

This is what I see with the :scriptnames command, you can see the standard files (line 32, 35) after the customer ones (line 31, 34)

```
31: /usr/share/vim/vimfiles/bundle/vim-javascript/syntax/javascript.vim                                                                                                                                            
32: /usr/share/vim/vim73/syntax/javascript.vim                                                                                                                                                                     
33: /usr/share/vim/vim73/ftplugin/javascript.vim                                                                                                                                                                   
34: /usr/share/vim/vimfiles/bundle/vim-javascript/indent/javascript.vim                                                                                                                                            
35: /usr/share/vim/vim73/indent/javascript.vim
```

Comment: Have you checked to see if it is perhaps the custom syntax file which is loading the normal one?

Comment: I checked it but it doesn't look to me as if it is loading the standard file... the syntax file is this https://github.com/pangloss/vim-javascript/blob/master/syntax/javascript.vim

Answer (score 3):

It's fine that both the system-default and your custom syntax files appear in the `:scriptnames` output. Vim will source all files found in `'runtimepath'`, but the canonical include guard

```
if exists("b:current_syntax")
```

will cause all scripts running after the first to abort immediately after the check.